# merge two files sorted numerically by an integer in each line without reading into memory and without sorting

Tags: python, merge, python-3.4

I have two files, file1 and file2, sorted numerically by column 2:

file1

```
A 1
B 10
```

file2

```
C 2
D 100
```

I want to merge them and get this output, which is also sorted numerically by column 2:

```
D 1
B 2
C 10
A 100
```

I can do it with this unix command, which doesn't sort, but merges the pre-sorted files:

```
sort -m -k2n,2 file1 file2
```

But how do I do this in Python 3.4 without reading the files into memory and without sorting? Python 3.5 will add a key parameter to heapq.merge() according to [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge), [bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org/issue13742) and [github.com](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py), but no pre-release is available. In the meantime I came up with the solution below. Is there a more elegant way? Could I have used [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and looped over the two files? Perhaps I should post to codereview instead?

```
import heapq

def key_generator(fd):
    for line in fd:
        yield int(line.split()[1]), line

with open('file1') as fd1, open('file2') as fd2:

    it1 = key_generator(fd1)
    it2 = key_generator(fd2)
    for key, line in heapq.merge(it1, it2):
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: This looks elegant to me. You can't use `map` without using extra temporary storage since sometimes you want to print several items from one list in a row, so you'd need to save the items you'd iterated past in the other list.

Comment: Your solution is just fine, this is called the [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) pattern.

Comment: @augurar Thanks for explaining the terms to a non programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded alpha release 1 of Python3.5 and I was able to do it by using the new [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function) of [heapq.merge()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge):

```
from heapq import merge

def keyfunc(s):
    return int(s.split()[1])

with open('file1') as fd1, open('file2') as fd2:
    for line in merge(fd1, fd2, key=keyfunc):
        print(line)
```

Or for those that prefer one line lambda functions:

```
key=lambda line: int(line.split()[1])
```

Could I have done this in one line using map, operator.itemgetter(), str.split and int?

Answer (score -2):

> You can try this way

```
dict={}

with open("a.txt",'r') as f1, open("b.txt",'rb') as f2:
    lines_a=f1.readlines()
    lines_b=f2.readlines()
    for line in lines_a:
        dict.update({line.split()[0]:int(line.split()[1])})

    for line in lines_b:
        dict.update({line.split()[0]:int(line.split()[1])})

for w in sorted(dict, key=dict.get):
  print w,(dict[w])
```

Comment: The OP stated he does not want to read the whole file into memory at once.  His solution only requires storing one line from each file at a time.